# SPARUL query to drop most graphs, using Jena API

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, apache-jena

I am trying to clear most of the graphs contained in my local [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) triple store, using Apache Jena, as part of my clean up process before and after my unit tests. I think that something like this should be done. First, I retrieve the graph URIs to be deleted; then I execute a SPARUL Drop operation.

```
String sparqlEndpointUsername = ...;
String sparqlEndpointPassword = ...;
String sparqlQueryString = ...; // Returns the URIs of the graphs to be deleted

HttpAuthenticator authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator(sparqlEndpointUsername,
            sparqlEndpointPassword.toCharArray());
ResultSet resultSetToReturn = null;
try (QueryEngineHTTP queryEngine = new QueryEngineHTTP(sparqlEndpoint, sparqlQueryString, authenticator)) {
    resultSetToReturn = queryEngine.execSelect();
    resultSetToReturn = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(resultSetToReturn);

    while(resultSetToReturn.hasNext()){
        String graphURI = resultSetToReturn.next().getResource("?g").getURI();

        UpdateRequest request = UpdateFactory.create() ;
        request.add("DROP GRAPH <"+graphURI+">");

        Dataset dataset = ...; // how can I create a default dataset pointing to my local virtuoso installation?

        // And perform the operations.
        UpdateAction.execute(request, dataset) ;

    }
}
;
```

Questions:

1. As shown in [this example](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/update.html), ARQ needs a dataset to operate on. How would I create this dataset pointing to my local Virtuoso installation for an update operation?
2. Is there perhaps an alternative to my approach? Would using another approach (apart from jena) be a better idea?

Please note that I am **not** trying to delete **all** graphs. I am deleting only the graphs whose names are returned through the SPARQL query defined in the beginning (3rd line).

Comment: In the absence of a `DROP ... WHERE ...` in SPARQL update I think that's the best you can do. The jena code can probably be cleaned a little, but fundamentally you need to do the 'graphs to remove' query, then the update.

Comment: @user205512 Thank you very much for your time. Could you provide a hint/answer for the 1st question?

Comment: Virtuoso [provide a driver](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider). The portable answer is via the sparql http protocol, which I assume Virtuoso supports, [DatasetAccessorFactory](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/DatasetAccessorFactory.html#createHTTP-java.lang.String-) might work?

Comment: Correction: The portable answer is via the sparql http protocol, which I assume Virtuoso supports. For queries [sparqlService](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/QueryExecutionFactory.html#sparqlService-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), and updates I think [something around here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/update/UpdateExecutionFactory.html#createRemote-org.apache.jena.update.Update-java.lang.String-)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question appears to be specific to Virtuoso, and meant to remove *all* RDF data, so you could use [Virtuoso's built-in `RDF_GLOBAL_RESET()` function](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRemoveTriples).

This is not a SPARQL/SPARUL query; it is usually issued through an SQL connection -- which could be JDBC, ODBC, ADO.NET, OLE DB, iSQL, etc.

That said, as you are connecting through a SPARUL-privileged connection, you should be able to use [Virtuoso's (limited) SQL-in-SPARQL support](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsqlfromsparql/), a la --

```
SELECT
  ( bif:RDF_GLOBAL_RESET()  AS reset )
WHERE
  {  ?s  ?p  ?o  }
LIMIT 1
```

(Executing this through an unprivileged connection like the default SPARQL endpoint will result in an error like `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Function bif:RDF_GLOBAL_RESET() can not be used in text of SPARQL query due to security restrictions`.)

(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I am not actually deleting all graphs. I am deleting the graphs whose names are returned through the SPARQL query defined in the beginning (3rd line).

Answer (score 1):

You can build a single SPARQL Update request:

```
DROP GRAPH <g1> ;
DROP GRAPH <g2> ;
DROP GRAPH <g3> ;
... ;
```

because in SPARQL Update one HTTP requests can be several update operations, separated by `;`.